# Data Loader v38 (Winter 17)

Tags: data-loader, winter17

I just downloaded Data Loader 38.0.0. The login has changed - instead of popping up a web window to log in, it just asks for user name, password and login URL (default is login.salesforce.com). I've tried both the production instance I'm trying to load to and my dev org. Neither has trusted IP ranges so security tokens should not be an issue. Nonetheless I get **Error: Check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce admin.**

The only login flow available to me in v38 is direct password authentication. I am offered OAuth in v37 and it works fine.

Any thoughts? Why was OAuth removed from v38?

Comment: Just wanted to add: I've been always logging into v37 via OAuth. There is no more visible OAuth option in v38.

Comment: Does it show anything helpful under your user login attempts?

Comment: Just the message cited above in bold. Fortunately Data Loader leaves the old version intact as well so I was able to spin up v37 and do what I needed. But why is OAuth missing from V38??

Comment: Tested in my MAC .Looks like oauth piece has disappeared .Not sure why

Comment: OK... how to best bring this to the attention of SFDC people?

Comment: @CharlesT Just to clarify. Are Trusted IP ranges setup for your current IP or not?

Comment: Without a Trusted IP range you **will** need to include the security token on the end of the password.

Comment: @DanielBallinger if that's the case it runs counter to the advice in the official Winter 17 guide (http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf): "If your organization restricts IP addresses, logins from untrusted IPs are blocked until they’re activated. Salesforce automatically sends you an activation email that you can use to log in. The email contains a security token that you must add to the end of your password. For example, if your password is mypassword, and your security token is XXXXXXXXXX, you must enter
mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX to log in."

Comment: So they advise the use of a security token **only** when you have a trusted IP range and you logged in from outside it.

Comment: Not supporting oauth is big thing for me .I was able to login though but removing ability to oauth is big deal

Comment: @CharlesT I assure you that you need to include the Security Token if the IP address you are authenticating from isn't in the Trusted IP ranges :).  My understanding is the Restricted IP addresses limits you to specific IP's, so the security token is no longer needed.

Comment: @DanielBallinger well - then it's poorly documented. The text says nothing about what the scenario is if your org *does not* restrict IPs. In any case the reason I ran into this was because they removed OAuth. That's a pretty serious omission.

Comment: OAuth is still there. Compile it yourself - it's pretty easy. https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader

Comment: @CasparHarmer most of the people in my company who use the Data Loader are admins not devs. The version of Data Loader that could be downloaded directly from Salesforce for Summer '16 offered OAuth as an option. It's missing in the Winter '17 release. Asking admins to compile it themselves or get a compiled version from devs is not helpful.

Comment: Are you under proxy? 
I was facing login issue with v38 under corporate proxy, after setting it up, worked fine.

Comment: You only need to compile it once and let all admins know of it's location. It genuinely is easy compile - I even have a compiled version on my computer that I'm happy to give you.

Comment: We're a partner so we're not just logging into our own org, we're logging into integration accounts of our clients as well. We are also providing admins at our client organizations with instructions on how to download and use the Data Loader. OAuth is the most convenient way for all of them.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Why is there anyway an OAuth feature present in your complied version that is not in the version Salesforce distributes? On what grounds would they have removed it?

Comment: I stand corrected sorry - I just opened it and it is missing the oauth piece. If I manage to put it back, I'll let you know. Very sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by Charles, [v38.0.1](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/38.0.1) is now available:

> DataLoader V38.0.1 fixed Oauth option missing issue caused by release script and a bug in field mapping UI after sorting by column names.

---

Partial answer, to at least get you going until the missing OAuth authentication can be resurrected.

You will need to append your security token to the end of the password unless your current IP address is listed under [Trusted IP Ranges](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm).

Conversely, if the Organization has [restricted IP addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_epui_login_ip_ranges_edit.htm) enabled you will only be able to login from those IP addresses and you won't need the security token.

I'll try [pinging the Salesforce Docs team](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/788143793560092672) to see if they can clarify the confusing point in the Data Loader documentation.

---

Caspars comment with the link to the [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) project would be a good place to raise the missing OAuth [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues).

Issue created by Mohith - [New Version 38.0 of dataloader has oauth option missing](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/123)

Randomly searching the projects code, it occurs to me that it will need to have access to the OAuth Client secret to get the flow started as the correct connected app. You can see this at [line 86 of AuthenticationRunner](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/5fd2ef7316da4cb137ded6fe81d708ac156ec408/src/main/java/com/salesforce/dataloader/ui/AuthenticationRunner.java#L86). If the sfdc.oauth.clientsecret was missing from the config then you wouldn't even get the OAuth option.

Comment: Issue opened https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/123

Comment: Thanks for getting this rolling. For the time being I don't see any conflicts in using the v37 data loader on a v38 org so I'll use that until I have confirmation that v38 is restored.

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed. New release will take a bit to roll out to orgs but I downloaded it straight from GitHub and OAuth is back!

Answer (score 0):

Dataloader needs certain configuration in place in order to show the OAuth login option. You can add configuration to solve this. Also the issue is now fixed in V38.0.1. Please download latest release. https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases